# Invalid XML code generated by web service

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, web-services, web2py

It seems like the `@service.xml` decorator is broken in [web services RPC](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10/services#Remote-procedure-calls).

```
@service.xml
def concat(a, b):
    return a + b
```

The result is:

```
>>> from urllib import urlopen
>>> r = urlopen("http://127.0.0.1:8000/webservice/default/call/xml/concat/hello/
world")
>>> r.read()
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>helloworld'
```

The last part is missing which produces invalid XML.

However, JSON and CSV work well.

```
@service.json
def concat(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Test:

```
>>> r = urlopen("http://127.0.0.1:8000/webservice/default/call/json/concat/hello
/world")
>>> r.read()
'"helloworld"'
```

I'm testing this in a copy of the scaffolding application. Am I missing something or this is really an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just a bad example in the book. To produce valid XML, the function should return a list or dictionary (or an object with a `.as_list`, `.as_dict`, or `.custom_xml` method). For example:

```
@service.xml
def concat(a, b):
    return dict(result=a + b)
```

produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
  <result>helloworld</result>
</document>
```